# Can I pack the html5 from playn to be use as IOS app?

Tags: ios, html, playn

Can I pack the HTML5 from playn to be used as an iOS app using some thing like phonegap, or another method?

Answer (score 2):

You can. Bear in mind that when using WebKit in a Phonegap-style application, you lose the benefit of just-in-time compiling in the JavaScript VM. So your game will be slower. If you don't need to integrate with the iOS App Store, a better solution is to have users get to your app via regular Mobile Safari and then click "Add to home screen" which will install your HTML5 app in a very app-like manner on their home screen and allow it to run with the JavaScript JIT.

Eventually PlayN will also support native compilation for iOS, but the above approaches are useful stopgaps if you plan to ship a game soon.

Comment: so what you're saying is that Phone-Gap converts html5 to native. If so how can it be slower?

Comment: PhoneGap does not convert HTML5 to native. It just runs a web browser (using UIWebView) in a native app. That embedded web browser is slower than Mobile Safari.